# Why does Visual Studio redify a method in a successfully built project? (morphed into "How can I bulk insert records into a SQL Server CE database?")

Tags: visual-studio, build, sql-server-ce, build-process, visual-studio-debugging

Normally red in the VS IDE means, "Danger, Will Robinson!" as in, you've got a compile-time error - something in the reddened part of your code is unrecognized or syntactically bogus.

However, I get both the redification of SqlCeEngine's CreateDatabase() method AND/BUT the project compiles:

[image]

Why the mixed messages/crossed signals?

Actually, when I step through the code at runtime, that line does fail because there is no such database in the location expected ("the file name is not valid..."); and both this line:

```
using (SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(dataSource))
```

...and this one:

```
using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(dataSource))
```

...have the hints, "*Constructor 'SqlCeEngine' has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked with 1 argument(s)*" ("*Constructor 'SqlCeConnection' has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked with 1 argument(s)*" in the second case).

It's true that, for some reason, there is no such database (at all - see [Why does creating a SQLServer Compact table in Server Explorer not create an .SDF file on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106393/why-does-creating-a-sqlserver-compact-table-in-server-explorer-not-create-an-sd)), but why does this code compile when it's apparently bogus?

Does the squiggly redness in the call to CreateDatabase() exist because, even at design-time, Visual Studio is checking and seeing that there is no such file?

### UPDATE

After shutting down and then restarting VS2008, the redification and the hints go away; but the app still fails at that point because of the missing database/table.

### UPDATE 2

What I find odd in looking more closely at this code (which I got from elsewhere as a starting point/template) is that the engine creation which is causing the problem doesn't seem to be needed: nowhere after this code is engine (the instantiation of a SqlCeEngine class) referenced...???

### UPDATE 3

When I change the logic to not reference the file path if the file does not exist:

```
if (File.Exists(sdfPath))
{
    using (var engine = new SqlCeEngine(dataSource))
    {
        engine.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
else
{   // Is "engine" necessary? Not referenced danach...
    using (var engine = new SqlCeEngine())
    {
        engine.CreateDatabase();
    }
    . . .
```

...it, as expected, runs the "else" clause; but then blows up on the no-arg constructor in that block with, "System.InvalidOperationException: The LocalConnectionString property has not been initialized yet. at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase()..."

### UPDATE 4

Curiouser and curiouser; the properties page for the SDF file I've got within my project (in Server Explorer), says that the path to the file is: Data Source=C:\Users\clay\Documents\HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf;Persist Security Info=True

Verblueffed because my previous disk-wide search for HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf found nothing, I looked in Windows Explorer for the file at the location specified above. There is no "Documents" folder below C:\users\clay! I thought, okay, maybe it means the "My Documents" folder, but clicking that folder provokes a roar from the bowels of the beast, popping up, "Location is not available. C:\Users\clay\My Documents is not accessible. Access is denied."

What in the whirled?!?

When I look at C:\Users\clay in Windows Explorer, its icon is decorated with the lock icon; so, I opened its properties and changed its Attributes by clicking in the "Read-only (Only applies to files in folder) checkbox.

Then the informational stuff above (Size, Size on disk, Contains) went nuts, cycling through numbers like the national debt meter.

### UPDATE 5

Now there are two My Documents folders beneath C:\Users\Clay

What the Hec Ramsey?!? How can that be? One apparently is a shortcut (?!?), as it has the NorthEast-pointing arrow decorating its southeast edge. The non-shortcut "My Documents" *does* contain HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf in it.

So ... why does Visual Studio think that the SDF file is in the "Documents" rather than the "My Documents" folder?

Windows Explorer claims that the SDF was created today at 1:57 - less than an hour ago. How did that happen? I created the database and table *yesterday*.

Something is rotten in Denmark, Wisconsin - or Salinas, California (perhaps the lettuce is wilting in the boxcars).

### UPDATE 6

I copied HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf to the location calculated by this code:

```
String appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
String sdfPath = Path.Combine(appDir, "HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf");
```

...and the FileExists logic for that file in that location:

```
if (File.Exists(sdfPath))
```

...fails. How could that be?!? I see it there in Windows Explorer! That odd sound you hear is follicles being ripped unceremoniously from my cranium mixed with muffled groans of maniacal desparation (H.D. Thoreau was right).

### UPDATE 7

The problem, the reason why the file was not being found, was because the logic calculating the location of the sdf file was producing exactly this:

```
file:\C:\WebAPIClient\WebAPIClient\bin\Debug\HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf
```

...and there is no "file:\" involved; so, changing it to:

```
sdfPath = @"C:\WebAPIClient\WebAPIClient\bin\Debug\HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf";
```

...did the ticket (the file is found).

### UPDATE 8

Who was it that said, "So close, and yet so far away"?

I've made good progress on this, getting to the call to WriteToServer(), but there I get, "*Specified cast is not valid. at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeUpdatableRecord.SetClrTypeValue(Int32 ordinal, Object value, String method)...*" If more detail is needed:

[image]

Why am I getting this InvalidCastException on "bc.WriteToServer(dt);" in this code:

```
private void buttonBulkInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Derived/adapted from test project for ErikEJ's Bulk Insert code for SQL Server CE databases; added reference to
    // ErikEJ.SqlCe.NetCF and System.Data.SqlServerCe
    //String appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
    //String sdfPath = Path.Combine(appDir, "HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf");
    // The above was prepending "file:\" which caused the file not to be found
    const string sdfPath = @"C:\WebAPIClient\WebAPIClient\bin\Debug\HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf";
    if (File.Exists(sdfPath))
    {
        File.Delete(sdfPath);
    }

    string dataSource = string.Format("Data Source={0}", sdfPath);

    using (var engine = new SqlCeEngine(dataSource))
    {
        engine.CreateDatabase();
    }
    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(dataSource))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCeCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE InventoryItems (Id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, PackSize smallint NOT NULL, InventoryName nvarchar(50), UPC_PLU nvarchar(50), VendorItemID nvarchar(50), Description nvarchar(255), Qty numeric, Cost numeric, Margin numeric, ListPrice numeric, Dept int, Subdept int);";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    // Create temp table that mirrors InventoryItems as a staging area for the data to be bulk copied
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PackSize", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("InventoryName", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UPC_PLU", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VendorItemID", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));

    //dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qty", typeof(double)));
    //dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cost", typeof(double)));
    //dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Margin", typeof(double)));
    //dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ListPrice", typeof(double)));
    // tried numeric, but it was not recognized...
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qty", typeof(float)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cost", typeof(float)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Margin", typeof(float)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ListPrice", typeof(float)));

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Dept", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Subdept", typeof(int)));

    // Some test data to add; replace later with looping through an IEnumerable or List<> or so...
    dt.Rows.Add("1", 1, "Some Inv Name", "123456UPCPLU", "Those Guys", "A rather short description", 10.2, 15.3, 20.4, 25.5, 42, 99);
    dt.Rows.Add("2", 1, "Another Inv Name", "234567UPCPLU", "Those Fellas", "Another rather short description", 11.2, 22.3, 33.4, 44.5, 42, 1);
    dt.Rows.Add("3", 6, "Yet another Inv Name", "345678UPCPLU", "Those Cats", "A rather moderate, by some standards, description", 20.2, 205.3, 2000.4, 20005.5, 42, 2);
    dt.Rows.Add("4", 12, "Still another Inv Name", "456789UPCPLU", "Those Bums", "Who needs a description, anyway?", 10.21, 15.32, 20.43, 25.54, 42, 3);
    dt.Rows.Add("5", 24, "What, another Inv name?!?", "012345UPCPLU", "Those Workaholics", "How can I describe something so indescribable? Huh?!?!", 110.2, 125.3, 230.4, 245.5, 42, 4);

    // Now move it all into the table
    using (var bc = new SqlCeBulkCopy(dataSource))
    {
        bc.DestinationTableName = "InventoryItems";
        bc.WriteToServer(dt);
    }

    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(dataSource))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCeCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM InventoryItems;"; // what's with the appended ";"?
            SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}-{6}-{7}-{8}-{9}-{10}-{11}{12}", reader[0], reader[1], reader[2], reader[3], reader[4], reader[5], reader[6], reader[7], reader[8], reader[9], reader[10], reader[11], Environment.NewLine);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

???

As can be deduced from the comment, I tried both double and float for the real numbers (numeric not allowed in the C# code), and in both cases the same err occurs. Maybe it's not those values?

### PENULTIMATE UPDATE

For posterity, here is the code that I finally got to work, with help from ErikEJ:

```
private void buttonBulkInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Derived/adapted from test project for ErikEJ's Bulk Insert code for SQL Server CE databases; added reference to
    // ErikEJ.SqlCe.NetCF and System.Data.SqlServerCe
    //String appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
    //String sdfPath = Path.Combine(appDir, "HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf");
    // The above was prepending "file:\" which caused the file not to be found
    const string sdfPath = @"C:\WebAPIClient\WebAPIClient\bin\Debug\HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf";
    if (File.Exists(sdfPath))
    {
        File.Delete(sdfPath);
    }

    string dataSource = string.Format("Data Source={0}", sdfPath);

    using (var engine = new SqlCeEngine(dataSource))
    {
        engine.CreateDatabase();
    }
    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(dataSource))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCeCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE InventoryItems (Id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, PackSize smallint NOT NULL, InventoryName nvarchar(50), UPC_PLU nvarchar(50), VendorItemID nvarchar(50), Description nvarchar(255), Qty numeric, Cost numeric, Margin numeric, ListPrice numeric, Dept int, Subdept int);";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    // Create temp table that mirrors InventoryItems as a staging area for the data to be bulk copied
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PackSize", typeof(Int16)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("InventoryName", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UPC_PLU", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VendorItemID", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qty", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cost", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Margin", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ListPrice", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Dept", typeof(Int16)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Subdept", typeof(Int16)));

    // Some test data to add; replace later with looping through an IEnumerable or List<> or so...
    dt.Rows.Add("One", 1, "Some Inv Name", "123456UPCPLU", "Those Guys", "A rather short description", 10.2, 15.3, 20.4, 25.5, 42, 99);
    dt.Rows.Add("2", 1, "Another Inv Name", "234567UPCPLU", "Those Fellas", "Another rather short description", 11.2, 22.3, 33.4, 44.5, 42, 1);
    dt.Rows.Add("3ree", 6, "Yet another Inv Name", "345678UPCPLU", "Those Cats", "A rather moderate, by some standards, description", 20.2, 205.3, 2000.4, 20005.5, 42, 2);
    dt.Rows.Add("4our", 12, "Still another Inv Name", "456789UPCPLU", "Those Bums", "Who needs a description, anyway?", 10.21, 15.32, 20.43, 25.54, 42, 3);
    dt.Rows.Add("5ive", 24, "What, another Inv name?!?", "012345UPCPLU", "Those Workaholics", "How can I describe something so indescribable? Huh?!?!", 110.2, 125.3, 230.4, 245.5, 42, 4);

    // Now move it all into the table
    using (var bc = new SqlCeBulkCopy(dataSource))
    {
        bc.DestinationTableName = "InventoryItems";
        bc.WriteToServer(dt);
    }

    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(dataSource))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCeCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM InventoryItems;"; // what's with the appended ";"?
            SqlCeDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}-{4}-{5}-{6}-{7}-{8}-{9}-{10}-{11}{12}", reader[0], reader[1], reader[2], reader[3], reader[4], reader[5], reader[6], reader[7], reader[8], reader[9], reader[10], reader[11], Environment.NewLine);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Alternate:

```
. . .
//if (File.Exists(sdfPath))
//{
//    File.Delete(sdfPath);
//}

string dataSource = string.Format("Data Source={0}", sdfPath);

if (!File.Exists(sdfPath))
{
    using (var engine = new SqlCeEngine(dataSource))
    {
        engine.CreateDatabase();
    }
    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(dataSource))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCeCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText =
                "CREATE TABLE InventoryItems (Id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, PackSize smallint NOT NULL, InventoryName nvarchar(50), UPC_PLU nvarchar(50), VendorItemID nvarchar(50), Description nvarchar(255), Qty numeric, Cost numeric, Margin numeric, ListPrice numeric, Dept int, Subdept int);";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
. . .
```

### FINAL UPDATE

And here is the "closer to reality" code - a method that receives an IEnumerable of the data and then posts it up. I added a for loop to it (not shown, just wrapped around the foreach loop) to test how long it would take to insert 1,080 records (instantaneous), 10,800 records (instantaneous), then 108,000 records (2 seconds), and finally 1,080,000 records (13 seconds*). Voila! Kudos and hats off to Larry, I mean ErikEJ!

- What, me instrument?!? These calculations were based on the second hand on my watch, nothing fancier. AND, it was on a test DESKTOP client app, albeit one targeting .NET 3.5. How much slower it will be on the actual handheld device, I don't know yet (I still haven't got past the connection issues to be able to try it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844344/why-does-my-handheld-client-not-find-my-servers-web-api-method)).

  private void BulkInsertInventoryItems(IEnumerable invItems)
  {
      const string sdfPath = @"C:\WebAPIClient\WebAPIClient\bin\Debug\HandheldSqlServerCompactDB.sdf";
      string dataSource = string.Format("Data Source={0}", sdfPath);

  ```
  if (!File.Exists(sdfPath))
  {
      using (var engine = new SqlCeEngine(dataSource))
      {
          engine.CreateDatabase();
      }
      using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(dataSource))
      {
          connection.Open();
          using (var command = new SqlCeCommand())
          {
              command.Connection = connection;
              command.CommandText =
                  "CREATE TABLE InventoryItems (Id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, PackSize smallint NOT NULL, InventoryName nvarchar(50), UPC_PLU nvarchar(50), VendorItemID nvarchar(50), Description nvarchar(255), Qty numeric, Cost numeric, Margin numeric, ListPrice numeric, Dept int, Subdept int);";
              command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
      }
  }

  // Create temp table that mirrors InventoryItems as a staging area for the data to be bulk copied
  var dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(string)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PackSize", typeof(Int16)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("InventoryName", typeof(string)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UPC_PLU", typeof(string)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VendorItemID", typeof(string)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qty", typeof(double)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cost", typeof(double)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Margin", typeof(double)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ListPrice", typeof(double)));
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Dept", typeof(int))); 
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Subdept", typeof(int)));

  foreach (WebAPIClientUtils.InventoryItem invItem in invItems)
  {
      dt.Rows.Add(invItem.Id, invItem.PackSize, invItem.InventoryName, invItem.UPC_PLU, invItem.VendorItemId,
          invItem.Description, invItem.Quantity, invItem.Cost, invItem.Margin, invItem.ListPrice,
          invItem.DepartmentNumber, invItem.SubdepartmentNumber);
  }

  // Now move it all into the table
  using (var bc = new SqlCeBulkCopy(dataSource))
  {
      bc.DestinationTableName = "InventoryItems";
      bc.WriteToServer(dt);
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: See my reply on Codeplex https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/workitem/24900

Comment: Maybe you should change the subject of the question